# Sorting priority

Tags: mongodb, sorting, meteor

I have a collection `Answers` in a MongoDB database and I sort the documents with the number of upvotes each answer has.

```
Answers.find({}, {sort: {voteCount: -1}})
```

Some of these answers, however, are posted by instructors and they should be sorted before of "regular" answers. Answer posted by instructors have a field `isInstructor: true`.
How do I retrieve my list of answers sorted in a way that instructors' answers come first (sorted by `voteCounts` as well) and then, after those, the normal answers (still sorted by `voteCounts`)?

Comment: can you show simple document with expected output? What about  `db.collection.find().sort({'isInstructor': -1, voteCount: -1})`?

Comment: Yay! Can't believe I was so stupid not to figure this out!! Thanks :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well As mention in my comment you must sort your `answers` by `isInstructor` in descending order and by `voteCount` in descending order. Also note that the second argument to [**`.find`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) is a projection document. Thus to sort your document you need to use the [**`cursor.sort`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/#cursor-sort) method instead.

```js
Answers.find().sort({ "isInstructor": -1, "voteCount": -1 })
```

Comment: `{ "isInstructor": -1, "voteCount": -1 }` Is the dictionary will be guaranteed to keep the ordering of key-value pairs? As I know, most languages don't guarantee to keep the ordering. So how would we know which one is more prioritized than the others?

Answer (score 2):

Use the cursor's sort() method, listing the fields you would like to sort by, in order. EG

```
db.answers.find({}).sort(isInstructor: -1, voteCount: -1})
```

Reference: [MongoDB Manual](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/)