# Mongoose: get latest records, then sort them by another field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm creating a quick leaderboard for a game. The leaderboard shows the most recent 10 players sorted by their score. My query doesn't seem to be working:

`recordModel.find({ game: gameId }).sort({updatedAt: -1}).limit(10).sort({ score: -1 }).exec( /*... */ );`

It only returns most recent 10 records without the seconds sorting.

How can I get the desired result? (Yes I know I can sort the result array by myself, but it doesn't feel "right" for me)

**Edit**: problem solved, but I cannot accept my own answer in 2 days. I will when the time comes, thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I solved the problem using `aggregate`:

`recordModel.aggregate([ { $match: { game: gameId} }, { $sort : { updatedAt : -1 } }, { $limit : 10 }, { $sort : { score : -1 } } ]).exec(/* ... */)`

Answer (score 2):

Can you try with only one "sort", like this ?

```
recordModel.find({ game: gameId })
    .sort({updatedAt: -1, score: -1})
    .limit(10)
    .exec( /*... */ );
```

More information here : [sorting-priority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31775814/sorting-priority)

Hope it helps.

Comment: No this doesn't work sorry. This is not a double criteria problem, I'm trying to sort the result of a query.